# Indexing a value in a nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary from an API request that looks somewhat like this:

```
{
"key 1": "value 1",
"key 2": "value 2",
"key 3": 
    {
        "key 4": "value 4",
        "key 5": "value 5",
        "key 6": "value 6"
    },
... # Additional fields here
}
```

And I need to save some values to another dictionary like `{"key 2": "value 2","key 5":"value 5"}`. In an attempt to make the code look nice I want to save the indexes of the values I need to keep in a list like `["key 2", "key 3/key 5"]`.

However I can't easily index a dictionary with `"key 3/key 5"` and was wondering if there is a way to do that.

For example:

```
dict={"username":"user",
      "email":"user@domain.com",
      "properties":{
          "favorite color":"blue"
          "favorite food":"apples"
          }
      }
savevalues=["email","properties/favorite food"]
```

which would return

```
{"email":"user@domain.com","favorite food":"apples"}
```

Comment: You example dict seems to be formatted incorrectly, missing an end brace?

Comment: Could you post the expected output, is not clear from the text what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're talking about using a list anyway, you could use nested lists/tuples to refer to indices in dictionaries within a dictionary.

```
d = {
"key 1": "value 1",
"key 2": "value 2",
"key 3": 
    {
        "key 4": "value 4",
        "key 5": "value 5",
        "key 6": "value 6"
    }
}

key_sets = (("key 2",), ("key 3", "key 5"))

for key_set in key_sets:
    value = d
    for key in key_set:
        value = value[key]
    print(value)
# value 2
# value 5


from functools import reduce


# `reduce` using key_sets above, a tuple or list of tuples or lists
print(tuple(
    reduce(
        dict.get, 
        key_set, 
        d
    ) for key_set in key_sets
))
# ('value 2', 'value 5')

keys = ("key 2", "key 3/key 5")

# `reduce` using '/'-separated nested keys, per the example in the question
print(tuple(
    reduce(
        dict.get, 
        key.split("/"), 
        d
    ) for key in keys
))
# ('value 2', 'value 5')
```

This assumes your key sets are always valid. If that's not an assumption you can make, you'll need to do some exception handling.

*Edited to add functional examples.*

Answer (score 0):

[`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html) is you new library friend, especially the `io.json.nested_to_record` function (haha.):

```
from pandas.io import json  
flat = json.nested_to_record(d)
savevalues=["email","properties/favorite food"]
print({i.split('/')[-1]:flat[i.replace('/','.')] for i in savevalues})
```

Whole demo:

```
d={"username":"user",
      "email":"user@domain.com",
      "properties":{
          "favorite color":"blue",
          "favorite food":"apples"
          }
      }
from pandas.io import json  
flat = json.nested_to_record(d)
savevalues=["email","properties/favorite food"]
print({i.split('/')[-1]:flat[i.replace('/','.')] for i in savevalues})
```

Output:

```
{'email': 'user@domain.com', 'favorite food': 'apples'}
```

I recommend this for speed, it's very fast, especially faster than loops :-), `pandas` is always the fastest in data stuff..., view documentation and be an expert on it...

Comment: Sorry, but a 40MB dependency and two layers of string manipulation is a really hard sell for a pretty simple problem... particularly one that can be reduced to `(reduce(dict.get, s.split("/"), d) for s in savevalues)` without adding any third-party libraries (just importing reduce from functools since this question is about Python 3.x).

Comment: I edited that into my answer after figuring it out for that comment. :) The main point was that your solution makes a lot more sense for a project that's already using pandas than one that would have to add it solely for this purpose.